# Dagger 2 inject dependences into a Fragment? Dagger stack?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using Dagger 2 DI framework in my app. Currently, I am creating the directory structure for my Authentication activity.

I have an AppComponent and AppModule which are scoped with ApplicationScope annotation.

For the individual activities I have @ActivityScope. I have one activity called AuthenticationActivity and its sole job is to present two Fragments - LoginFragment and SignUpFragment so the user can swipe a viewpager to change between the two. Now, my question is how should I arrange my dagger stack? Do I need to create a subComponent for the LoginFragment, for example like that

```
@Subcomponent(modules{})
public interface AuthenticationComponent{
    LoginComponent plus(LoginModule module);
}
```

And my LoginComponent could look something like that:

```
@Subcomponent(modules{LoginModule.class})
public interface LoginComponent{
    void inject(LoginFragment fragment);
}
```

My app component will look similar:

```
@Component(modules={AppModule.class})
public interface AppComponent{
    AuthenticationComponent plus(AuthenticationModule module);
}
```

I am just wondering if there is a more elegant way (e.g. avoiding the creation of the AuthenticationComponent).

Comment: You can.  You don't have to.  Heck, if you wanted to you could just have 1 global component that does everything.  The question is what value do you think you'd derive by having a subcomponent?  I don't see much here.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for your comment. I don't think I am injecting anything into AuthenticationActivity. The purpose of this activity is pust to show those two fragments with the use of a viewpager. So I guess I am not gaining any value of having a authenticationActivity subcomponent.

Comment: @GabeSechan I guess I got confuse of having that many nested subcomponents and I automatically thought that I am doing it wrong (first time using Dagger 2 in a big project )

Comment: I'd say no need for a subcomponent.  The big usecase for subcomponents is when your main component is just getting really big and you have a lot of semi-related components you can move into one, OR when working on a large project where different teams may own 1 (or a few) subcomponents and cut down on merge conflicts that way.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for the valuable advice! I will not create a subcomponent for now and see how things are in the feature. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think two scopes (`ApplicationScope` and `ActivityScope`) are enough. Just inject your fragments via specific activity component.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. However, I was not asking weather or not to inject a whole Fragment into the activity. I was just asking do I need this AuthenticationComponent at all since the stack is getting 2 levels deep (with two subsomponents)

Comment: i am not sure if i understand you well but you definitely do not need two subcomponents.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer! :)

Comment: @YMY while not needed for this case, I like adding a 3rd scope-  user scope.  It provides a clean way of keeping and get rid of objects that should stick around as long as the user is logged in-  auth tokens, user data structures, etc.